# What is more important for images - alt tag or name

Tags: seo

I am making a blog with huge ammount of images, and one way to do it, is by using Flickr Gallery plugin, which provides a functional gallery or your albumbs, but the links aren't looking good (www.......5129512891.jpg), but they do have the proper alt tags (Red Carpet From Turkey).

So now I am wondering if I should stay with this Flickr gallery, because it eases my job thousand times, or I should look for a way to have both good link (www.......red-carpet-turkey.jpg) and an alt tag. (I am talking about a blog, primarily for images, not just here and there).

My goal is to appear in Google Images first, for example, when someone types "Red carpet from turkey", and click on images, I want my pictures to be first in the results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: explain please what is the 'seo' tag for

Comment: See its description ("Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters"). The tag (which I think is not very useful) is used for questions that have a SEO background. It’s fine to ask here on SO if you have a problem implementing something for SEO, but it’s off-topic to ask what is better for SEO or what search engines allow/disallow/prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So now I am wondering if I should stay with this Flickr gallery, because it eases my job thousand times, or I should look for a way to have both good link (www.......red-carpet-turkey.jpg) and an alt tag.

Google searches for keywords in the filename and in the alt tag for an image. It also searches relevancy information in the surrounding text (see here for [image SEO](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/seo-photography-images-naming.html) - disclaimer I maintain that post).

> My goal is to appear in Google Images first, for example, when someone types "Red carpet from turkey", and click on images, I want my pictures to be first in the results.

Then you want a relevant filename, alt tag and surrounding text. You must make sure the quality of the image is good (Google checks it for ranking). You can also create an image sitemap to help crawlers find your images.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are important for SEO score. Its important to set **alt tags** and a **related name** for the image. You have to decide if its profitable to change every image name or let them as they are.

Take care with the **image size**, it matters too.

Comment: Image size matters? Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: @JVerstry Sure it does. It's important to resize images for making the web load faster; load time was one of the variables Google used for SEO ranking. On the other hand, users normally don't wait more than 4-5 seconds for a web to load, so reducing this time is always positive.

Comment: No, John Mueller has repeatedly said load time is not a ranking factor in his webmaster hangout videos (unless the load time is extremely slow 20-30s per page). Load time does impact user experience and it may have an indirect impact on ranking on the long term, but no direct SEO impact.

Comment: Thats the point. Thank you for explaining it clearly. It's always good to learn something new.